# first round submission VS second round submission in academic conferences

Tags: conference, paper-submission

I submitted a paper for an academic conference, and I have been accepted but the reviewer asked for modifications. But I am confused on when I should send the final paper (it's not specified on the notification of acceptance)

Here's what it's written in the conference website:

---

**2nd Round Submissions:**

Paper Submission: 30 August 2018

Decision Notification: 15 September 2018

Author Registration & Final Paper: 25 September 2018

**1st Round Submissions:**

Paper Submission: 10 July 2018

Decision Notification: 10 August 2018

Author Registration & Final Paper: 10 September 2018

---

**So, do I send the final paper 10 September 2018 or 30 august 2018?** Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing the actual system used, nor their history, I can only assume that if you submitted in the first round then nothing in the second round description applies to you at all. Your final paper would be due by 10 September.

It seems as if the conference, in having two rounds, is protecting itself against not having sufficient accepted papers in one round and so permits authors to send papers late for possible review.

If I'm correct, and it seems likely, they want the final paper before they need to make decisions about the second round on 15 September.

If they had wanted you to "resubmit in the second round" they would, I hope, be explicit about that and wouldn't have talked about your paper being "accepted".

You can ask the program committee for clarification, of course. But earlier is better in any case.

Comment: Maybe I'm mixing everything. I assumed that are also talking about a paper publication. but actually in the letter it's written "Congratulations! We are pleased to inform you that your above paper has been accepted for presentation at *** [...]to the conditions below. After you complete the requirements below, your paper will appear in conference proceedings and will be submitted to***.Extended versions of best papers will appear in ***journal". So for now i'm just accepted for an oral presentation (if i do the modifications) but not a publication ?

Comment: It seems clear to me. Use the Round 1 deadlines since you submitted to Round 1 originally. It also seems pretty clear that you will appear in print if you meet conditions - at least in the proceedings of the conference. It also sounds like some of the best papers will then be _invited_ to write a longer version for the journal, but that would have completely separate deadlines - not the Round 2 deadlines. They expect an "expanded version" if that happens.

Comment: They sent 3 times the same email and add in the last one "We also hope that you will submit your excellent new work to the **2nd round submissions by 30 August 2018** ". So what does it mean? my work is not good enough to be in the first round submission?

Comment: @learneRS, I'm pretty sure that it means _other_ work. Stick to the round 1 deadlines for this paper.

Comment: Thank you but i'm sorry i don't understand what you mean by "I'm pretty sure that it means other work". "other work"?

Comment: @learneRS, not this paper, but other papers that you might also be working on. They are inviting you to submit future work, it seems.

Comment: Thanks again. At this point sending them an email and asking is the best option